# Spring Boot Oauth2 Dependecy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0

I want to create a simple program based upon oauth2 authentication including Auth server, resource server and client. I found there are various of dependencies used by online tutorials. I am confused why spring provides so many dependencies for oauth2. What is difference between below dependencies and when to use them. And which oauth2 dependency comes with springboot.

The First line is group-id and next line is artifact-id

1. org.springframework.security

   spring-security-oauth2-client
2. org.springframework.security

   spring-security-oauth2-jose
3. org.springframework.security

   spring-security-oauth2-core
4. org.springframework.security

   spring-security-oauth2-resource-server
5. org.springframework.security.oauth

   spring-security-oauth2
6. org.springframework.security.oauth.boot

   spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure
7. org.springframework.cloud

   spring-cloud-starter-oauth2

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a simple program based upon oauth2, then you can use the dependency from the point 7 and spring-cloud-starter will pick up the dependency itself under your version of Spring & Spring Cloud :)

The last point (7) contains all of the above. But if you don't need all dependencies from the 7, then import it into the project separately (1-6).